# Steps to install Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ) ActiveX?

Tags: c#, delphi, activex, msmq

On Windows Vista Business, I installed the MSMQ core components but I can not see a 'Microsoft Message Queuing' ActiveX (I want to import it in Delphi).

To verify my install, where should I look for the ActiveX file? The MSMQ service is installed and uses an executable in the system directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.borlandtalk.com/threaded-com-msmq-listener-on-client-app-not-a-com-server-vt109777.html shows that there must be MSMQ type library (it uses MSMQ_TLB and types like MSMQQueueInfo, and code like FQueue := CoMSMQQueue.Create;)

To create the Delphi wrapper code you can use the following command:

```
tlibimp -P c:\windows\system32\mqoa30.tlb
```

This will create a pas and a dcr (component resource) file

Comment: It's not working on Delphi7 for MSMQ 3.0 - "Element not found" error is raised. Any ideas?